# Reorder tabs in Magento 2 mobile menu, in the navigation-sections group

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, navigation, header

I have added a new section to the `navigation-sections` block in the header, so that I can include it in the mobile menu. The element is displayed correctly, but I cannot change the order of the tabs, to have a new "Welcome" tab show first (by default it shows last). Is there a way of ordering group items?

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.mobile-welcome" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml" before="store.menu">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Welcome</argument>
        <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.mobile-welcome-message" template="Magento_Theme::html/mobile-welcome.phtml" />
</block>
```

I have tried using `before="store.menu"` and passing a `priority` argument, and neither are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's old but may someone want to use it.

```
<argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
```

This is OK but you should implement your function in the sections.phtml file as well(DO NOT OVERRIDE CORE FILES) just make a copy and modify it something like this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
    ?>
    <?php
    /**
     *  General template for displaying group of blocks devided into sections
     */
    $group = $block->getGroupName();
    $groupCss = $block->getGroupCss();
    $groupBehavior = $block->getGroupBehaviour() ? $block->getGroupBehaviour() : '{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}';
    ?>
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames($group, 'getChildHtml')): ?>
        <div class="sections <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>">
            <?php
            $layout = $block->getLayout();
            $newPriority = array();
            ?>
            <div class="section-items <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-items" data-mage-init='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupBehavior ?>'>
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
                    <?php
                    $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
                    if (!trim($html) && ($block->getUseForce() != true)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
                    $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');



                    $priority = $block->getChildData($alias, 'priority') ? $block->getChildData($alias, 'priority') : '10';
                    ?>
                               <!-- <div class="section-item-title <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-title" data-role="collapsible">
                                    <a class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-switch" data-toggle="switch" href="#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $alias; ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $label; ?></a>
                                </div> -->

                    <?php array_push($newPriority, ['alias' => $alias, 'label' => $label, 'priority' => $priority, 'html' => $html]); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php
                # Sort array by priority
                usort($newPriority, function($a, $b) {
                    return $a['priority'] <=> $b['priority'];
                });
                foreach ($newPriority as $section):
                    ?>
                    <div class="section-item-content <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $groupCss ?>-item-content" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $section['alias']; ?>" data-role="content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $section['html']; ?></div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```